# limit and bounded linear function problem in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Suppose $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is a linear function.

1)Is $f(x)/\|x\|$ a bounded function of x on?

2) If $f$ is not the zero map, prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x)/\|x\|$ does not  exist.

I think the first problem is not bounded, but I am not very sure. And I have no clue what to do with the second question.

Comment: If $f(x) = x$, what is your answer?

Comment: the tag (ounded variation) is wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\frac{f(x)}{\|x\|} = f \left( \frac{x}{\|x\|} \right)
$$
by linearity. Since $S^{n-1} = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid \|x\|=1\}$ is a compact set and $f$ is continuous, then you deduce immediately that your function is bounded.

Now suppose without loss of generality that $f(e_1) \neq 0$, where $e_1=(1,0,\ldots,0) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and pick $x=\varepsilon e_1$ for $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}$. Then
$$
\frac{f(\varepsilon e_1)}{\|\varepsilon e_1\|} = \frac{\varepsilon}{|\varepsilon|} \frac{f(e_1)}{\|e_1\|},
$$
and this expression has no limit as $\varepsilon \to 0$.

Comment: Why do we use $S^1$ ?

Comment: Sorry, just a typo.